# How to write quiz on arduino

Tags: string, arduino-ide, character-arrays

I am trying to write a 5 question quiz on arduino that has three possible answers and outputs a score at the end. I am trying to write it where it asks the first question and after someone inputs their answer, it goes to the next question. I am having trouble with the initializer before the "." token error message. can you help me?

```
`typedef struct{
  char question[];
  char answer1[];
  char answer2[];
  char answer3[];
  char correct_answer;
  }question_t;

question_t questions[] = {questions[0], questions[1], questions[2], questions[3],           questions[4]};
question_t questions[0].question = "1. What is the capital of Illinois?";
question_t questions[0].answer1 = "a) Chicago";
question_t questions[0].answer2 = "b) Springfield";
question_t questions[0].answer3 = "c) Carbondale";
question_t questions[0].correct_answer = 'b';

question_t questions[1].question = "2. Who is the governor of Wisconsin?";
question_t questions[1].answer1 = "a) Scott Walker";
question_t questions[1].answer2 = "b) Clay Matthews";
question_t questions[1].answer3 = "c) Cole Nebel";
question_t questions[1].correct_answer = 'a';

question_t questions[2].question = "3. Where is MSOE?";
question_t questions[2].answer1 = "a) Memphis";
question_t questions[2].answer2 = "b) Manitowoc";
question_t questions[2].answer3 = "c) Milwaukee";
question_t questions[2].correct_answer = 'c';

question_t questions[3].question = "4. Why is Justin Bieber in jail?";
question_t questions[3].answer1 = "a) DUI";
question_t questions[3].answer2 = "b) bad music";
question_t questions[3].answer3 = "c) looking like Miley Cyrus";
question_t questions[3].correct_answer = 'a';

question_t questions[4].question = "5. Who is Jim Jefferies?";
question_t questions[4].answer1 = "a) actor";
question_t questions[4].answer2 = "b) singer";
question_t questions[4].answer3 = "c) comedian";
question_t questions[4].correct_answer = 'c';

int score;
int i;
char c;

char read_user_input(char c);
void output_question(uint8_t i);
void output_score(void);


loop()
{
  init();
  score=0:
  uint8_t i;
  i=0;
  while(i<5)
  {
    output_question(i);
    c=read_user_input();
    if(c==questions[i].correct_answer)
    {
      score=score+20;
    }i++;
  }
  Serial.print(output_score());
}

void init(void)
{
  questions[5]:

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code.

```
typedef struct{
  char question[];
  char answer1[];
  char answer2[];
  char answer3[];
  char correct_answer;
}question_t;
```

You need to give your arrays a length.

```
question_t questions[] = {questions[0], questions[1], questions[2], questions[3],           questions[4]};
question_t questions[0].question = "1. What is the capital of Illinois?";
question_t questions[0].answer1 = "a) Chicago";
question_t questions[0].answer2 = "b) Springfield";
question_t questions[0].answer3 = "c) Carbondale";
question_t questions[0].correct_answer = 'b';
```

These declarations are wrong. To initialize an array you need to use a *brace enclosed initializer* (what the first line has). Otherwise the *object.member* syntax you have used needs to be inside a function (without the preceding type name).

To initialize the array you will need to do it in one statement.

```
struct question_t{
  char question[30];
  char answer1[30];
  char answer2[30];
  char answer3[30];
  char correct_answer;
};

question_t questions[] = {
  {  
    "Question 1",
    "Answer 1",
    "Answer 2",
    "Answer 3",
    'a'
  },
  {  
    "Question 2",
    "Answer 1",
    "Answer 2",
    "Answer 3",
    'b'
  },
  {  
    "Question 3",
    "Answer 1",
    "Answer 2",
    "Answer 3",
    'c'
  }  
};
```

---

> I am having trouble with the initializer before the "." token error
>   message

Once you have the data declared correctly these errors will be solved. Unfortunately you will have other errors further down, however I'll leave them up to you (should be easy to fix).